# jquery: get and add some data to a table structure

Tags: jquery, html

This is my tablestructure.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
         <td>
         <input type="text"> 1 </input>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
         <input type="text"> 1 </input>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
          <div class="sum"> </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

I have a onblure event on the input field

```
( $("input[type=\"text\"]").blur(function()...)
```

Now I want get both values of the inputfields if one of them gives the blur event.  Add those values and post them to the sum div. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add some `class` and/or `id` attributes to your inputs so that this code will play nicely if dropped into a larger HTML context.  However, to answer the question as given:

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type=text]").each(function () { // For each of the two inputs
        sum += parseInt($(this).val())       // ... add its value to sum
    });
    $("div.sum").text(sum);                  // Update the div
});
```

If you're entering numbers with a decimal point, you'll probably want to use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt`.

**UPDATE:** If your structures are all like the one posted, the easiest way to relate them to one another would be to use an `id` attribute on the containing table, and the descendant selector syntax.  Then the code would look like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).parents('table').attr('id');
    var sum = 0;
    $(parentId +" input[type=text]").each(function () { 
        sum += parseInt($(this).val())   
    });
    $(parentdId + " div.sum").text(sum);
});
```

**UPDATE AGAIN:** Okay, so you have no way to assign ids to your tables.  That's okay, we can still get this done.  You'll have to use jQuery's traversal functions `parent()` and `find()` instead of simple selectors, that's all.

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents('table');
    var sum = 0;
    parent.find("input[type=text]").each(function () { 
        sum += parseInt($(this).val())   
    });
    parent.find("div.sum").text(sum);
});
```

Comment: looks nearly perfect the problem is i have a lot of this constructions so there are a couple of this tables in the document so i need a way to do that by keep in mind which table contains the element which changed

Comment: my problem is that i write this tables in a partical view and i have no value to identify the tables and i can't add a simple counter too.. :S

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready ( function() {
            $("input[type='text']").blur( function () {
                CalculateSum();
            });
        });

        function CalculateSum ()
        {
            var sum = 0;

            $("#tableID input[type='text']").each ( function() {               
                if ( !isNaN ( $(this).val() ) )
                {
                    sum += parseFloat ( $(this).val() );
                }
            });

            $(".sum").text ( sum );
            // If you can give the div an id and fill the value.
            //$("#sum").text ( sum );
        }
```